# How to use export insde a function with ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to export the client.db() after the connection but the problem is that the default export must be at the top level of a file or module declaration.

this is my code.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import app from "./app.js";

const client = new MongoClient("connect to mongodb")

async function start() {
    await client.connect()
    export default client.db() 
    app.listen(3000, ()=> {
        console.log("Your server is running at port 3000")
    })

}
```

I tried to create a global variable and set it equal the client:db() inside the start() function, the export default get the variable as the initial value "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modules, you can actually use top-level awaits in most situations.  Assuming there aren't any weird cross-dependencies, you can do something like this:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import app from './app.js';

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Your server is running at port 3000.');
});

const client = new MongoClient('connect to mongodb');    
await client.connect();
export default client.db();
```

Answer (score 0):

Default exports should always be at the top level of a file or module declaration and there is no workaround about this.

However, there is a solution for what are you trying to achieve by using the singleton pattern. You can read more about this pattern on the link below:

[Singleton Pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/singleton-design-pattern-with-javascript/)

Your main goal is to be able to export just a single instance of the client db and you want every part of your application to use that same instance.

You can achieve this by using the below implementation:

```js
import {
  MongoClient
} from "mongodb";

const client = new MongoClient("connect to mongodb")

let clientDb = null;

async function getClientDb() {

  if (clientDb) return clientDb;

  await client.connect();
  clientDb = client.db();

  return clientDb;
}


export default getClientDb;
```

Now in order to use your db instance where you need it, simply import the ***getClientDb*** function and use its resolved return value.